# Incompatible declaration error while providing an implementation for a method

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Getting the error:

> declaration is incompatible with 
> LinkedList::toString() const

This is how I have declared the function:

```
string toString() const;
```

And, while defining this is what I have done:

```
#include "ListInterface.h"
#include "node.h"
#include <string>

template <class ItemType>
class LinkedList : public ListInterface<ItemType>
{
public:
vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
    string toString() const;
}
```

They seem to be exact same I am not sure what I am missing here.

I have defined the following two classes:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "ListInterface.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class ItemType>
class LinkedList : public ListInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    Node<ItemType> *headPtr;
    int itemCount;
   
public:
    vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
    string toString() const;
};
 
#endif   
  
template <class ItemType>
string LinkedList<ItemType>::toString() const
{
    std::string ListContents;
    Node<ItemType> *curPtr = headPtr;
    int counter = 0;
    while ((curPtr != nullptr) && (counter < itemCount))
    {
        ListContents += (curPtr->getItem());
        curPtr = curPtr->getNext();
        counter++;
    }
    
    return ListContents;
}
```

Comment: `std::string` ... `string` is not a type on its own.

Comment: I suspect `using namespace std;`

Comment: Also, no sign of `#include <vector>` in the shown code. We need to see all your relevant code.

Comment: I have updated the code. I got totally confused while posting it. The `#include <vector>
` is there in another header file `ListInterface.h` I think it should be fine now. So namespace std; is there and #include <vector> too

Comment: Your code is still a very long way from anything reproducible by others ... but that `#endif ` near the middle of your code block looks especially strange.